# Microsoft Word Convert WordArt to regular text while keeping the formating and rotation

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

I am trying to convert WordArt in a document into normal text in order to perform operations on it. I want it to remain with the same formatting and rotation. The wordart is diagonal white text

Image

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ltrR.png)

Here is the document

[Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nOtYpHaaXEnX4mt8gMy5MVxBfnGAC6VI/view?usp=sharing)

A second option - I imagine - would be to create a table, rotate it and hide the margins.

I am avoiding Text-boxes and Shapes as they  wont give me the result which I want when I perform operations on the document.

How can I best achieve this?